# jQuery Resizable trigger resize with dimensions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I would like to know how i could manually trigger the `resizable(`) event from jQuery ui.
I actually have a `<div>` that users can resize with the `resizable()` handle.
In the `resizable()` function I've set the `aspectRatio` parameter to `true`.

Now I also have an `<input type="text />`, in that input users can type a custom height value.

The question is: How can I trigger the `resizable()` event on that `<div>` with the new dimensions (height only) set by the user keeping the aspect ratio (width/height) ?

Comment: do you mean that the user gives up the size and the div resizes to that height and the width is adjusted automaticly with aspectratio?

Comment: Yes this is exactly the intended result